# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't not open/appear on click:

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/wwwroot/js/datePicker.js"></script>
```

datePicker.js:

```
 (function ($) {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 })(jQuery);
```

html:

```
 <td>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
 </td>
```

css:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I cannot understand why the calendar does not open when I click on the text input field. What am I doing wrong? Strange thing is when I isolate these elements in a small html with the scripts inline it seems to work.

edit: full html

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/simpleControls.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/MassScheduler/schedulerLayout.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/MassScheduler/massScheduler.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/MassScheduler/schedulerManager.js"></script>
    <script src="./wwwroot/js/MassScheduler/schedulerController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/wwwroot/js/MassScheduler/schedulerTableFilter.js"></script>
    <script></script>
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" ng-app="massScheduler">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ng-view:

```
<div ng-controller="schedulerController as vm">
    <div id="scheduler-index-main">
        <scheduler-form ng-show="!vm.showErrorMessage"></scheduler-form>
        <scheduler-status-table ng-show="!vm.showErrorMessage"></scheduler-status-table>
        <div ng-show="vm.showErrorMessage" id="error-message">
            <h4>Error occurred. Please try again later.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No errors are output to the console. I replaced the path for datePicker.js. It is finding the file, I can see it in Chrome tools. the input is not showing however.

Comment: Hard  to say, from what you have posted that should work without issue. There must be something else on your full page that is causing your issue https://jsfiddle.net/ygfdzekd/

Comment: Has to be a path issue. check ur console, and post the error!!

Comment: @Iceman no errors reported in console. I'm wondering if this is an issue working with Angular routing as well?

Comment: @JohnDoe replace `~/wwwroot/js/datePicker.js` with absolute path.

Comment: Why are you combining jQuery **and** angular??? Angular has plenty of good directives for date pickers. For instance here is Angular bootstrap. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, check if your js path is ok("~/wwwroot/js/datePicker.js").

```js
 (function ($) {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<td>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
 </td>
```

Comment: This isn't really an "answer" and should probably be a comment. But you are correct in that there is nothing wrong with the code that is posted. Something else, possible path as you suggest, is causing the problem.